# empty array when subscribing to service that returns Observable

Tags: firebase, ionic2, lodash, angular2-services, angular2-observables

I'm subscribing to a service to get an Array of Teams

teamService code:

Here my teamService code (get results from firebase):

```
getTeams(): Observable<Team[]> {
    this.login();
    let teams: Team[] = [];
    return this._db.list('teams')
      .map((response) => {
        response.forEach(team => {
          this._fb.storage().ref().child('teams/' + team.photo).getDownloadURL()
            .then(imageUrl => {
              teams.push(new Team(team.id, team.name, imageUrl, team.zone, team.points, team.matchesPlayed,
                team.matchesWon, team.matchesDrawn, team.matchesLost, team.goalsScored,
                team.goalsReceived, team.dif));
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log(error);
            });
        });
        return teams;
      });
  }
```

Here I'm subscribing to my service to get the teams:

```
loadStandings() {
    let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      spinner: 'crescent'
    });
    loading.present();
    this.teamService.getTeams().subscribe(t => {
      this.teams = t;
      console.log('showing this.teams');
      console.log(this.teams); // this.teams declared as any[]
      this.teamsOrdered = _.orderBy(this.teams, ['points', 'dif'], ['desc', 'desc']);
      console.log('showing this.teamsOrdered');
      console.log(this.teamsOrdered); // this.teamsOrdered declared as any[]
    });
    loading.dismiss();
  }
```

`console.log(this.teams)` shows me the expected array returned from the service but `console.log(this.teamsOrdered)` is empty.

Lodash is imported `import * as _ from 'lodash';` at the top of my ts file

Here screenshot from console

[image: console output]

Edit: I added my getTeamsService code, when debugging (put a breakpoint on `console.log(this.teams);` I realized that the code below `this.teams=t` is executing before the values are retrieved from the service call.
If I don't debug then the result are in the same from my console output screenshot.

What  am I doing wrong?

Comment: adding a `skipWhile` operator before you `subscribe` will work

Comment: thanks for replying. I can't figure out how skipWhile operator fix my issue. I read this doc https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/skipwhile.html
Is there a way to ensure my orderby is executed once I have values on `this.teams` and `this.teams.length==10`?